# Dispose pattern in F#

Tags: f#, dispose

In F#, inheritance is less common than it is in C#, but that doesn't mean it's never used.

If I am inheriting from a type that implements `IDisposable` in C#, I would normally use the [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) to suppress the finalizer. However, I can't do this directly in F#, because there is no `protected` access modifier.

I've searched online for an implementation of the Dispose Pattern in F#, but I've only found naive interpretations of `Dispose()`. Is there a pattern that lets me release unmanaged resources in derived classes, while still suppressing the finalizer for performance optimisation?

To make this question slightly less abstract, here is a typical abstract base type which I would like to inherit from:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type ContentPage<'TViewModel, 'TView when 'TViewModel :> ReactiveViewModel and 'TViewModel : not struct>(theme: Theme) as this =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let messageReceived (message: AlertMessage) = this.DisplayAlert(message.Title, message.Message, message.Accept) |> ignore
    let mutable viewModel, listener = Unchecked.defaultof<'TViewModel>, Observable.Never<AlertMessage>().Subscribe(messageReceived)
    do base.BackgroundColor <- theme.Styles.BackgroundColor
    member __.ViewModel with get() = viewModel and set(value: 'TViewModel) = listener.Dispose(); viewModel <- value; listener <- value.MessageSent.Subscribe(messageReceived)
    abstract member CreateContent: unit -> View
    interface IViewFor<'TViewModel> with member __.ViewModel with get() = this.ViewModel and set(value) = this.ViewModel <- value
    interface IViewFor with member __.ViewModel with get() = (this :> IViewFor<'TViewModel>).ViewModel :> obj and set(value: obj) = (this :> IViewFor<'TViewModel>).ViewModel <- (value :?> 'TViewModel)
    interface IDisposable with member __.Dispose() = listener.Dispose()
    override __.OnAppearing() =
        base.OnAppearing()
        match box this.Content with
        | null -> this.Content <- this.CreateContent()
        | _ -> this |> ignore
```

What would `Dispose()` look like if I were to implement an F# analog of the C# Dispose pattern?

Comment: `protected` is the least important aspect of that idiom. Make it public instead and get on to more important things. ;-] That said, suppressing finalization only matters if your type has a finalizer, and `ContentPage` doesn't, so it's kind of a moot point IMO...

Comment: That will certainly do the job. :)

Comment: Fair point about the Finalizer, but this is an abstract base class, and I've got no control over what people decide to do with their derived classes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have managed resources, so do you really need the full Dispose pattern? Why not make the Dispose method overridable?

Comment: @RobLyndon : Good point!

Comment: @Asti -- I could, but if someone fails to call base.Dispose() then the listener won't be disposed.

Comment: @Rob : `Dispose` is an optional contract; different languages encourage calling it to varying degrees (C++/CLI being the most effective), but it is nonetheless optional. If your code is semantically incorrect if `Dispose` _isn't_ called, then the dispose "pattern" is in fact an anti-pattern for you and you should enforce deterministic cleanup some other way.

Answer (score 4):

You can't implement the `Dispose` call chain directly in f#. `base.Dispose()` won't work since `base` is of type `ContentPage` and won't be implicitly casted to `IDisposable`.  `base` only allows member access so you can't cast it explicitly either.  The following won't compile.

```
type BrokenPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()

    interface IDisposable with 
        member __.Dispose() =
            (base :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

To get around this another method is needed.  Since there is no `protected` in F#, the idiom still isn't perfect.

```
type ContentPage() =
    abstract Close : unit -> unit

    default this.Close() = 
        // cleanup ContentPage here
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this)

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = 
            this.Close()


type SomePage() =
    inherit ContentPage()

    override this.Close() = 
        // cleanup SomePage here
        base.Close()

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = 
            this.Close()
```